# Spring forward is not working in android api

Tags: spring-mvc

I have been search on google but I can not find the solution so please tell me why spring forward is not working in android api but working in web api so how to fix it?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public ModelAndView home(@ModelAttribute LoginInfo user, Model model,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LoginController.user.userName: "+userName);
        return new ModelAndView("forward:admin.html");
      }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView successAdmin(@ModelAttribute LoginInfo user, Model model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("admin.userName: "+userName);
        return null;
    }


}
```

I also use return new ModelAndView("forward:/admin.html"); but not forward the request to /admin handler method.

Comment: can you show what is working and what is not?

Comment: @Simon actually request is not forwarded from first handler method to second one.

Comment: when I hit this url http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/ in web browser then return forward is working but when I hit from the same url from android app then return forward in first handler method is not worked ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
return new ModelAndView("admin.html");
```

in your home method

or change the home function to

```
public String home() {   
    return "forward:/admin";
}}
```

Comment: simon this works in web api but does not work when hit from android app.Why?Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does anybody have an idea about the problem?

Comment: If you are running your code on a web server, it doesn't matter where the source comes from, maybe there is something wrong with your admin page, which can not be parsed by the android app or browser.

Comment: return is not working and how I troubleshoot the problem I am little upset about the solution because I know the problem but I am unable to find the solution